# R progress bar not captured in log file when directed from bash

Tags: r, logging, centos, progress-bar, stderr

In linux, when I am re-routing the output of an R code which contains a progress bar (from progressr package), the progress bar is not captured in the log file (i am monitoring the log file with `tail -f output.log`). I need this setup to work as one of my applications which executes R codes is monitoring these logs files and displays them in its GUI.

Below is the code I have tested in centos 7 (R 4.0.2). This code is in a file called test.R.

```
require(progress)
require(progressr)

slow_sum <- function(x) {
  p <- progressr::progressor(along = x)
  sum <- 0
  for (kk in seq_along(x)) {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    sum <- sum + x[kk]
    p(message = sprintf("Adding %g", x[kk]))
  }
  sum
}

progressr::handlers(
  list(progressr::handler_progress(
    format   = ":spin :current/:total (:message) -- [:bar] :percent in :elapsed ETA: :eta\r",
    width    = 60,
    complete = "+")))
progressr::with_progress(y <- slow_sum(1:10))
```

Then when I try to execute this code as follows from terminal

```
R --no-save --args < ~/test.R >> output.log 2>&1
```

and monitor the progress using `tail -f output.log`, I dont get any progress bar updates in the log file. Anybody any leads?

Comment: Check this document https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/progressr/vignettes/progressr-intro.html specifically the section "Progress updates in non-interactive mode ("batch mode")" - I can't test from where I am but hopefully that gives you something to try

Comment: Thanks for the right direction. Unfortunately it only solves the problem when I remove the handler call (i.e. if I use the default handler). Might be an issue with progressr or progress package, I also reported this as an issue in github.

Comment: I realized that each handler requires also enable = TRUE `... list(progressr::handler_progress(enable = TRUE...` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Paul's comment I got a good lead. Two separate things needed to be done, `options(progressr.enable=TRUE)` and `... list(progressr::handler_progress(enable = TRUE...` . These enable progressr messages in non-interactive mode.